# Is possible convert ‘QStringList’ to ‘unsigned char’?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QStringList and I want to convert it to unsigned char[32].

Is possible? And how do I do that?

Example:

```
publicKey = "0x46,0x9e,..."
auto queryPK = publicKey.split(',');
```

so that is my qDebug()

```
queryPK[0] is 0x46

queryPK[1] is 0x9e
```

And that is what I want to have after conversion:

```
unsigned char pk = {0x46,0x9e,...}
```

Comment: What do you mean, a QStringList with 32 positions?

Comment: No, QStringList is an object, unsigned char[32] is an array of 32 characters.  I think what you are actually meaning is how to I get an array from a string list?

Comment: I guess you can start looking here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: @SPlatten yes! that is what I want to do

Comment: @LaionCamargo you have to say more, do you want concatenate the strings from the QStringList into the `char32]` ? with/without separators between ? What about the non ascii char ?

Comment: @bruno I fix my question to give more info ;)

Comment: This code makes nosense. It is invalid

Comment: Do you mean your QStringList[0] contains the string "70"  ?  And you want to convert that to a single byte with the value 70 ? Do all the strings in your list contain a string representation of a number that fits in an unsigned char ?

Comment: @LaionCamargo each QString into the QStringList has always 1 character ?

Comment: @bruno, If each values of the `QStringList` is a `QString` of length 1, why do you not use `QList<QChar>` ?

Comment: @ThibautB. this is the more probable thing looking at the description given by Laion Camargo but I/we wait for confirmation :)

Comment: @bruno Yep sorry, I wanted to notify Laion Camargo, but I do a mistake ;)

Comment: `for (const auto &s, stringList) int i = s.toInt();`, assuming that each element in the string list can be converted to an integer value.

Comment: I give more example to help understand what I want, sorry for the bad information before ;)

Comment: ok, so queryPK[0] is not 70, nor "70" but "0x46" ! etc

Comment: @bruno yep! I just left 70 because its the real value in Int

Comment: @LaionCamargo from  vahancho proposal `char * ppk = pk;  for (const auto &s, stringList) *ppk++ = s.toInt(0, 16);` or something like, probably adding test of length etc

Comment: @Amadeus I fixed the example ;)

Comment: @LaionCamargo no, replace `queryPK[0] >> 0x46` by `queryPK[0] is "0x46"` etc else is very confusing. To say _publicKey_ is a _QString_ is also useful

Comment: @bruno maybe has some mistake... pk is the result I want to have after send my stringList into a unsigned char pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your QStringList contains something like that:

```
QStringList sl = QStringList() << "0x46" << "0x9e";
```

A possible solution is:

```
unsigned char pk[32];
int idx = 0;
for (const QString& s : sl){
    // transform to uint
    bool converted = false;
    unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(s.toUInt(&converted, 0));
    if (converted){
        pk[idx] = uc;
    }
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: Wrong sizeof and in general not what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Better, but the second parameter of `toUInt` should be 0 (as you want it to parse the `0x` prefix); also, you should check if the conversion succeeded through the first parameter...

Comment: @MatteoItalia Fixed ;)

Comment: @ThibautB. tks Sir... that fix my problem!!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your list as described in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#iterating-over-the-strings).

So, basically you need something like this (assuming that `queryPK` is your `QStringList` object):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;

QStringList::const_iterator constIterator;
for (constIterator = queryPK.constBegin(); constIterator != querypk.constEnd();
       ++constIterator)
    v.emplace_back(std::stoul(constIterator));
```

but you must ensure that `constIterator` is 1 byte long or you will get narrowing conversion

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `toAscii().constData()`.

```
QString str = "ABCD";
int length = str.length();
unsigned char *sequence = NULL;
sequence = (unsigned char*)qstrdup(str.toAscii().constData());
```

be aware, that you have to delete the sequence with the following code:

```
delete [] sequence
```

You have to add the split logic and a loop to have your full solution.

Comment: Not what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: But it is a part of what he want's to achieve, i also mentioned that in my answere.